# F# - Generate Random Subset of List With Sums Of Singles And Pairs

Tags: list, random, f#, subset

I would like to generate an output list, which is a randomly generated subset of the original input list of size count and separately sum the singles and pairs in the output list, I show three sample output lists and their associated singles and pairs sums in the code below:

```
let input = [1; 1; 2; 2; 3; 3; 4; 4; 5; 5; 6; 6; 7; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11]
let count = 11
let random = System.Random()
let output = 
    List.map (fun x -> input.[random.Next(input.Length)]) 
    input
    |> Seq.take(count)
    |> Seq.toList

printfn "%A" output

// Output: [1; 1; 2; 2; 3; 3; 4; 4; 5; 5; 6]

// Sample 1: [1; 1; 2; 2; 3; 3; 4; 5; 8; 9; 11]
// Singles: 5 Pairs: 3
// Sample 2: [1; 2; 2; 3; 4; 5; 5; 6; 6; 7; 7]
// Singles: 3 Pairs: 4
// Sample 3: [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11]
// Singles: 11 Pairs: 0
```

Comment: I think you may want to look at `seq.groupBy` - but what part exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: I appear to be generating only [1; 1; 2; 2; 3; 3; 4; 4; 5; 5; 6] on each iteration.

Comment: You appear to want the count and not the sum. why only singles and pairs? you could get 1 1 1 1 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one error in your code, `input` should come on the same line as your `map`, or alternatively pipe into it. Otherwise you can just accomplish what you want with functions:

```
let output = 
    input 
    |> List.map (fun x -> input.[random.Next(input.Length)])  
    |> Seq.take(count)
    |> Seq.countBy id |> Seq.groupBy snd |> Seq.map (snd >> Seq.length)
    |> Seq.toList
```

Obviously you have no guarantee that you only will get singles or pairs.

**Add 1**

Your random function doesn't do what you think it does. It randomly selects elements from your original list, however you have no guarantee that the random number generator won't give you the same number three times in a row for example. So you can end up with `[10,10,10]` in the list. So for your second comment, in case you just want to shuffle the list, use `SortBy`. And for your first comment, I just defined a record that keeps the shuffled list and also the count. You would need to add some more error handling logic as depending on the count, it's possible to get a list with only singles or pairs. Also I made `output` into a function that takes two parameters, the input list and the count. It's more idiomatic and easier to work with.

```
type ShuffledList = {
    counts : int list
    original : int list
}

let output input count = 
    let original = 
        input 
        |> List.sortBy (fun _ -> random.Next()) 
        |> Seq.take(count) |> Seq.toList
    let counts = 
        original
        |> Seq.countBy id |> Seq.groupBy snd |> Seq.map (snd >> Seq.length)
        |> Seq.toList
    {counts = counts ; original = original}

output input count
```

Comment: How do I generate both the new list and the counts?

Comment: Note from the input list, [1; 1; 2; 2; 3; 3; 4; 4; 5; 5; 6; 6; 7; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11], 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 can appear as either singles or pairs but 8,9,10,11 can only appear as singles. Triples or above are not allowed.

Comment: @matekus see my addition to the answer, especially the part on shuffling and random sampling with replacement. You could also use some library function to do this from MathNet.Numerics.

Comment: One slight change in your code - "let counts = input" should be "let counts = original"...

Comment: In the counts, sometimes the order of singles and pairs is reversed?

Comment: @matekus that is indeed possible. you will need additional logic for error handling (when there are either no singles or pairs) as well as the identifying them. I suggest you give it a try and if you need some more help with it maybe post another Q?